# Compound configuration in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I have several applications. Each of them is deployed in its own application server. It's done this way because it minimizes time to redeploy each application when a change is made only in that application. This is because only one app server with one application will be restarted, which takes less time.

Anyway, I need to start all of those application servers in a certain order and in debug mode. Intellij IDEA has a compound configuration which allows you to start multiple applications. But it has 2 significant flaws: it doesn't allow you to specify the order in which applications should be started and it seems to not allow to start them in debug mode. So is it possible to somehow achieve those goals?

Comment: What kind of application servers? Tomcat? Jetty? NodeJS? Microsoft? Legos?

Comment: IntelliJ -- no, Kubernetes, Docker Composer, etc. -- yes. You're using the wrong tool.

Comment: what are you talking about Engineer dollery? How would kubernetes and docker compose help you start apps in IntelliJ in debug mode without having to attach to each with remote debugging?

Answer (score 22):

The **multirun** plugin is a better implementation for this. You can define the run order and even more importantly **debug** works.

https://github.com/rkhmelyuk/multirun

Comment: if the plugin says "incompatible with this version of intellij" when you try to install it, make sure your build number matches the compatible build number from the download list.

Answer (score 5):

You can add tasks to a Run/Debug configuration and configure their order with before launch options.

[image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-launcher.html#before-launch-options
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181164